# Printing values following comparison of two csv files only if in a specific range using Python 3.3

Tags: python, csv

I'm new at programming and I've got two CSV files that I'm trying to compare. The first file, snp.csv is shown below:

```
chrom   position    ref var gene        var
1       21421       G   T   WASH7P      snp.LOH
1       1251593     T   C   CPSF3L      snp.somatic
6       107474777   -   A   PDSS2       indel.somatic
14      106586168   G   T   ADAM6       snp.LOH
```

The second file, quad.csv is shown below:

```
chrom   Start   End     Sequence
1       21420   21437   GGGACGGGGAGGGTTGGG
1       23058   23078   GGGCTGGGGCGGGGGGAGGG
1       23515   23534   GGGAAGGGACAGGGCAGGG
1       45098   45118   GGGAAAGGGCAGGGCCCGGG
3       1148    1173    GGGCCGGGCAAGGCCGGGTGCAGGG
```

I want to compare these two files and if the two chrom values match, I want to print only those having position value (in snp.csv file) in the range of the start and end value (in the quad.csv file).
So, I am looking for a solution that will give me something like the following (basically the snp.csv file with start, end and sequence value of the quad.csv file)

```
chrom   position    ref var gene    var     Start   End     Sequence
1       21421       G   T   WASH7P  snp.LOH 21420   21437   GGGACGGGGAGGGTTGGG
```

I've searched the posts and found some interesting answers that helped me a lot but I’m still experiencing some issues. I’m still learning Python…

Here is my script up to now, I know I have a problem with the range function...I'm stuck

```
import csv

snp_file = open("snp.csv", "r")
quad_file = open("quad.csv", "r")
out_file = open("results.csv", "wb")

snp = csv.reader(snp_file, delimiter='\t')
quad = csv.reader(quad_file, delimiter='\t')
out = csv.reader(out_file, delimiter='\t')



quadlist = [row for row in quad]

for snp_row in snp:
    row = 1
    found = False
    for quad_row in quadlist:
        results_row = snp_row
        if snp_row[0] == quad_row[0]:
            quad_pos = range(quad_row[1], quad_row[2])
            if snp_row[1] in quad_pos:
                results_row.append(quad_row)
                found = True
                break
        row = row + 1
    if not found:
        pass
    print (results_row)



snp.close()
quad.close()
out.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from bisect import bisect_right
from collections import defaultdict
import csv

TOO_HIGH = 2147483647   # higher than any actual gene position
SNP_FMT  = "{0:<7} {1:<11} {2:3} {3:3} {4:11} {5:15}".format
QUAD_FMT = " {1:<7} {2:<7} {3}".format

def line_to_quad(line):
    row = line.split()
    return int(row[0]), int(row[1]), int(row[2]), row[3]

def line_to_snp(line):
    row = line.split()
    return int(row[0]), int(row[1]), row[2], row[3], row[4], row[5]

class Quads:
    @classmethod
    def from_file(cls, fname):
        with open(fname, "rU") as inf:
            next(inf, None)   # skip header line
            quads = (line_to_quad(line) for line in inf)
            return cls(quads)

    def __init__(self, rows):
        self.chromosomes = defaultdict(list)
        for row in rows:
            self.chromosomes[row[0]].append(row[1:])
        for segs in self.chromosomes.values():
            segs.sort()

    def find_match(self, chromosome, position):
        segs = self.chromosomes[chromosome]
        index = bisect_right(segs, (position, TOO_HIGH, "")) - 1
        try:
            seg = segs[index]
            if seg[0] <= position <= seg[1]:
                return (chromosome,) + seg
        except IndexError:
            pass

def main():
    quads = Quads.from_file("quad.csv")

    print(  # header
        SNP_FMT("chrom", "position", "ref", "var", "gene", "var") +
        QUAD_FMT("chrom", "Start", "End", "Sequence")
    )

    with open("snp.csv") as inf:
        next(inf, None)   # skip header line
        for line in inf:
            snp = line_to_snp(line)
            quad = quads.find_match(snp[0], snp[1])
            if quad:
                print(SNP_FMT(*snp) + QUAD_FMT(*quad))

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

which gives

```
chrom   position    ref var gene        var             Start   End     Sequence
1       21421       G   T   WASH7P      snp.LOH         21420   21437   GGGACGGGGAGGGTTGGG
```

Comment: When I tested it on my full set, I got this: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\snp_gquad_stackoverflow.py", line 60, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Python33\snp_gquad_stackoverflow.py", line 44, in main
    quads = Quads.from_file("quad.csv")
  File "C:\Python33\snp_gquad_stackoverflow.py", line 24, in from_file
    return cls(quads)

Comment: the following error is: File "C:\Python33\snp_gquad_stackoverflow.py", line 28, in __init__
    for row in rows:
  File "C:\Python33\snp_gquad_stackoverflow.py", line 23, in <genexpr>
    quads = (line_to_quad(line) for line in inf)
  File "C:\Python33\snp_gquad_stackoverflow.py", line 12, in line_to_quad
    return int(row[0]), int(row[1]), int(row[2]), row[3]
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1;11008;11026;GGGCGGGGGTTGGGGGGG'

Comment: @user3429339: you told us the quad-file was space-separated, and apparently it is actually semicolon-separated! You can fix this by changing row 11 to `row = line.rstrip().split(";")`.

Comment: Ok thank you. But I still don't get the meaning of these two lines: SNP_FMT  = "{0:<7} {1:<11} {2:3} {3:3} {4:11} {5:15}".format
QUAD_FMT = " {1:<7} {2:<7} {3}".format. Where can I get information about the syntax? Any links you can suggest me?

Comment: It's a combination of string-formatting and tuple-unpacking; instead of storing the format-string and calling mystr.format(arg, arg, arg) I store the bound object method mystr.format as a function reference, then call myfn(*args). The result is the same, I just find it syntactically cleaner.